# Chown files of mounted raspbian image to a user that isn't on host system

Tags: linux, user

I have an init script that `mkdir -p raspi-os-image/home/pi/.ssh` and adds a SSH key to `authorized_keys` inside. The problem is, when doing this it needs to be done as root and then once the system is initialized, the `pi` user cannot save anything new into `known_hosts` due to `~/.ssh` being owned by `root`.

When I am on the linux environment that has the OS image mounted (where I make the `mkdir` call) I am unable to run `chown pi:pi raspi-os-image/home/pi/.ssh` because `pi` is not a valid user on this system.

Is there any way to do this? Must I create a `pi` user on this system?

Comment: Have you considered moving the configuration to the Pi with something like Puppet, chef or Ansible?

Answer (score 2):

The directory does **not** need to be owned by user `pi`.

Indeed the filesystem has no inherent knowledge of users.

`pi` is user `1000`, and your system probably has a user `1000`.

You should be able to use numeric users with `chown`.

Comment: Yeah, when I added a user `pi` to that system and used that, it set to user 1001 (pretty straightforward to see why that is), and that doesnt match `pi` on the `pi`, and it works even worse than if it was root... so thanks for showing me that this is can be the ID too.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just SCP the files to the RPI, and then `sudo chown pi:pi file` when logged on to the RPI?